# Determining Components of an Experiment

Tags: statistics

> Let's say that there is a study that focuses with the effect of storage times on the calcium content of barley. Samples of barley were stored for different times (either $0,1,2,$ or $4$ months) and the calcium content was measured (grams of Ca per kg of barley). We suppose that this study is balanced and a total of $35$ samples were taken.

**Initial Ideas**

Our **subjects** (or units) would our samples of barley, our **treatement** would be the different storage times ($0,1,2,$ or $4$ months) and lastly, our **response** (or conclusion) would be the amount of calcium content that was collected from the barley.

Based on the description above, one of the questions had to do with whether this study was a *design experiment* or an *observational study* and I chose the former because the researchers were in control of assigning the treatments to our subjects. How does this sound?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an experiment investigators apply treatments to experimental units (people, animals, plots of land, etc.) and then proceed to observe the effect of the treatments on the experimental units.

In an observational study investigators observe subjects and measure variables of interest without assigning treatments to the subjects. The treatment that each subject receives is determined beyond the control of the investigator.

As such, yours is clearly an experiment, since you are exploring effect of treatments.

Comment: This definitely clears up my doubts whether a study is either a design experiment or an observational study. Just a quick inquiry: is it true that observational studies focus more on randomization (using a chance device perhaps) as opposed to a design experiment?

Comment: @JohnSmith not sure, i am sorry

Comment: It's okay I figured it out. Appreciate your insight.